# Help understand why question closed for being too broad and what to do about it

Tags: support

My [Question](https://superuser.com/questions/1318235/scenario-to-produce-ntlm-traffic) was closed due to it allegedly being too broad.

Is it because my question can have multiple correct answers?
Is it because I did not specify which part NTLM I am interested in?

Please help me understand why it was considered so.
Also I am not able to edit or comment to fix the question. So what can I do to improve my question?

Thanks

Comment: 1/ You haven't told us what you have already tried. 2/ If you perform some reading on NTLM it will answer your questions.

Comment: @DavidPostill, I read about NTLM for more then a day and I tried creating virtual machines with windows 10 and doing RDP and file sharing from one machine to another. To no avail.

Comment: [Microsoft NTLM (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378749(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I found that I can use windows xp to create the scenario.  Just to have one windows xp access other windows xp share will produce ntlm traffic. Too bad I am not able to add answer - so someone else would not waste so much time to figure a way to produce ntlm traffic. Thanks anyway David for trying to help.

Comment: If you are willing to answer your own question (perhaps clarifying it a little first) then I'm willing to reopen it.

Comment: Sure @DavidPostill

Comment: Reopened and unlocked.

Comment: *Reopened and unlocked* and still no answer after 8 days.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Answered now.